# Why the following jquery code crashing in IE8 but working fine in other browsers like chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to play a video when an image is clicked. I have browsed lots of sites and gathered bits and pieces here and there. I have not done much jquery before and at the moment I am learning it.

The code that is marked in between commented lines is crashing in IE 8, I am using JQuery 1.5.1

```
var img_container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ad-image');
var img = $(new Image()).attr('src', image.image);            
img_container.append(img);

this.image_wrapper.prepend(img_container);

/*****************************************/
img_container.click(function () {
      $('<object> </object>', { class: 'videoContainer', id: 'vid' }
       ).append = $('<param name="movie" value="http://youtube.com/v/jxXukpxNSx4&hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1"/>' +
      '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>' +
      '<param name="height" value="344"/>' +
      '<param name="width" value="425"/>' +
      '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>').prependTo('.ad-image-wrapper');
});
        /********************************************/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this `.append =`.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

```
$('<object> </object>', { class: 'videoContainer', id: 'vid' }
   ).append =
```

I think you want this:

```
img_container.click(function () {
  $('<object> </object>', { class: 'videoContainer', id: 'vid' }
   ).append($('<param name="movie" value="http://youtube.com/v/jxXukpxNSx4&hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1"/>' +
  '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>' +
  '<param name="height" value="344"/>' +
  '<param name="width" value="425"/>' +
  '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>')).prependTo('.ad-image-wrapper');
});
```

With `.append()` as a method call.

Also, in the first part of your code, you are mixing and matching jQuery and regular javascript DOM manipulation.  Always do it the jQuery way, because it will take care of the cross-browser compatibility issues.  Instead of this:

```
var img_container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ad-image');
var img = $(new Image()).attr('src', image.image);            
img_container.append(img);
```

Do this:

```
var img_container = $('<div class="ad-image">');        
img_container.append('<img>', { src: image.image });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Jeff@ When img_container div is clicked I want to display a video dynamically.

Comment: I meant, what are you trying to append to what?  But I think I figured it out.  You are making an object, appending the parameters, and then prepending the whole thing to `.ad-image-wrapper` right?

Comment: yes you are right. I just realised this code not working even in other browsers. I did some thing wrong before posting here.

Comment: @coolcake: Your other code could use some fixing, too.  See my edit.